Shimmer effect for Delete requests
We have implemented Shimmer effect on our data tables to show the "loading state". When the table is loading, the skeleton is loaded and the shimmer effect is rendered simultaneously. Whenever I delete a row in a data table(For DELETE API calls) what are the different ways I can show these loaders?
Note: I need a consistent loading mechanism throughout the application.
Solution I have: I have only greyed out the row which would be affected by the delete Operation.

"… throughout the application" – what kind of application? It looks like you are looking for a standard indeterminate loader for the entire application. Does the application only consist of tables? It will also be good to know the expected loading time.

If I understand correctly, you want to give user feedback when deleting a row in a table, or in any other parts of the app.
There are mainly two ways of doing this:

You can animate the row and make it disappear right away (shrinking, fading, sliding, etc.), while executing the API call. If the API call fails for whatever reason, you add back the row, while showing an error notification.

You can mark the row as inactive (transparent, loading spinner, "deleting..." text, greyed out, etc.) and execute the API call. If the API call is successful, then the row disappears (with or without animation). If the API call fails, the row returns to its default state, while showing an error notification.


Which solution is better depends on your API integration:

If your API calls are fast and reliable, with high success rate, then solution no.1 is preferred, since it gives the user instant feedback and satisfaction.
If your API calls are slow or they might fail, then solution no.2 is the more reliable one.

This approach can be applied to any delete feature in the app. The visual details (how the row looks or animates) are less important, as long as the feedback is clear, accessible and consistent with your overall app design.
